# HOME is not set when exploiting a vulnerability

Tags: environment-variables, home

I have an error
sh: line 61: cd: HOME not set.

[image]

Distribution: Metasploitable 2 (Ubuntu 8.04)

`/root/.bashrc` (comments and whitespace removed):

```
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
shopt -s checkwinsize
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(lesspipe)"
if [ -z "$debian_chroot" -a -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi
case "$TERM" in
xterm-color)
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
;;
*)
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
    ;;
esac
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;${USER}@${HOSTNAME}: ${PWD/$HOME/~}\007"'
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac
if [ "$TERM" != "dumb" ]; then
    eval "`dircolors -b`"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
fi
```

cat /root/.profile

```
# ~/.profile: executed by Bourne-compatible login shells.

if [ "$BASH" ]; then
    if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
    fi
fi

mesg n
```

ps -p $$ -ocomm=

```
sh
```

I tried to use "rlogin -l root x.x.x.x" from my kali to this machine, but it did not work. The .rhosts files are ok, but i get this error message, so maybe this is the reason why it doesnt work.

1) login with telnet using backdoor at 1524

[image]

2) login with samba userman script exploit:

[image]

3) ssh with password (cd is working):

[image]

Comment: What distribution is this? Just set the ``HOME`` environment variable. What shell are you using?

Comment: Please `cat /root/.bashrc` and `cat /root/.profile`

Comment: @MichaelDurrant no, we'd rather have all information here. That's what [code blocks](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) are for.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add i) your OS; ii) if Linux, your distribution; iii) the files that Michael Durrant asked for; iv) your shell (`ps -p $$ -ocomm=`)

Comment: Try commenting out the `case "$TERM"` `esac` part

Comment: `rlogin` is hopefully disabled because it's highly insecure. Usr `ssh` instead. Then a `root` login is also not encouraged, use a normal account, then `sudo` for doing root tasks.

Comment: @Michael Durrant: I tried it, but i did not help.

Comment: @ott-- I know. I am a student, and this problem is from my pentesting practice.

Comment: How are you logging in? On a text console? At a GUI prompt? Over the network, and if so how? Or are you running a shell by exploiting a program which was not intended to log users in?

Comment: is your `cd` command maybe aliased to a shell script? what does `type cd` say? what happens if you use `\cd` in place of plain `cd`?

Comment: Thanks for the responds, I added the info to the question. I changed the root password and logged in with root, and cd worked. I use metasploit framework's exploits (like userman script samba exploit) and try to login with telnet too. I dont know the details, how can I find out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you log in via a normal method (on the console, over SSH, etc.), the program handling the login sets a few environment variables, including `HOME`. If you get access to a shell not via logging in, but by exploiting a vulnerability in a program, you get that program's environment, which often but not always includes `HOME`.

In bash, for some reason, the `cd` command with no argument uses the value of `HOME` as the target. Tilde expansion, however, falls back to the home directory from the user database (e.g. `/etc/passwd`) if `HOME` is not set. So if `HOME` is not set, `cd` complains, but `cd ~` changes to the user's home directory. `cd $HOME` runs `cd` with no argument when `HOME` is not set.

When you're exploiting a vulnerability, you can't count on the environment being a familiar one. It's part of the craft of making an exploit — the easy part — to go from being able to execute code (e.g. having a shell) to setting up a convenient environment to run standard code.

Comment: if you are in `sh` or `bash`: if/when `HOME` is not set, you can set it via `if [ -z "${HOME:-}" ]; then export HOME="$(cd ~ && pwd)"; fi`